# How can I call a dictionary with user input

Tags: python, string, dictionary, input

I'm new to programming. My project is a credit card award points optimizer written in Python 3. I have a few dictionaries based on spending categories, with the keys/values representing my credit cards and their point multiplier for that category.

After showing the user the categories, it asks them to input which one they want to make a purchase in, and here's where I'm getting an error because the input is a string and my dictionary is a variable.

How can I convert the string into a variable, so that I can print the keys/values?

Example category and list of categories

```py
dining = {'amex': '4x points'}
categories = ['dining', 'grocery']
```

input and call script

```py
purchase_type = input('Which category is it?: ')
for category in categories:
            if purchase_type == category:
```

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 1):

You can put your various category dictionaries into a dictionary themselves. Then you can just plug the input like `selected = categories[theirInputVariable]`